# Free open source browser inline SVG editor (alternative to Gliffy)

Tags: document-management, drawing, wiki

[Gliffy](https://www.gliffy.com/) is an amazing browser inline SVG editor to make drawing part of your Wiki.

For a public sector environment, is there a free open source alternative?

Which features matter:

- Integration with MediaWiki and/or Confluence
- Versioning of drawings
- Native SVG data format
- Extensible shape libraries
- Ideally, will well integrate with available PDF interface of the wiki tool